# How much time do I have untill the job status is no longer available?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing-service

After launching a SubmitJob operation, how much time is left before the job status is no longer available?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS server? Which Version?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS Server 10.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dependent on your Job folder setting.
If I remember correctly, it's set to a default of 10 minutes.
Read this [help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/#/Managing_the_jobs_directory/002v0000000m000000/), it explains how to set the value. You can use that knowledge to check the value and change it if you need.